# How can I move my UIView in xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uiview

I have a view controller with a collection view on it. I dragged a `UIView` onto the view controller as you can see below.

[image: I attached a label, also note the white border is from the collection cell.]

I attached a label, also note the white border is from the collection cell.

Then, In the `CollectionViewController` class that is attached to the actual view controller, (the `UIView` doesn't have a custom class) I created an outlet and attached it to the `UIView`.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *infoView;
```

Then I synthesised it: `@synthesize infoView;`

Now, in the `ViewDidLoad` method, I want to be able to move the view down out of the screen so its not visible.

I have tried using `CGRect` and `CGPointMake` but it just doesn't move! Can someone show me the **exact** code I can use to move the `UIView` by my desired amount within the `ViewDidLoad` method?

Comment: No need to synthesize, are you using auto layout? laying out views should not be done in viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 0):

First remove the view from superview

```
[infoview removeFromSuperView];
```

After that you can adjust the new frame of view

```
infoview.frame = CGRectMake(x,y,width,height);
```

Now add the view again to superview

```
[self.view addSubVeiw:infoView];
```

To animate a view to a new frame, use the following code

```
infoView.frame =  CGRectMake(x,y,width,height);//initial frame
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
       infoView.frame =  CGRectMake(x,y,width,height);//new frame
    }];
```

Comment: sweet it worked! but what about if I want to animate its movement?

Comment: it seems to start from the "new Frame" and animate towards the " initial frame", do i need to remove it from the super view before animating or something?

Comment: @Josh In animation, you do not need to remove the view.

Comment: @Josh Have you tried animating your view in `viewDidLayoutSubview`?

Answer (score 0):

Subviews are not properly set yet in `viewDidLoad`.
Try moving your subview in

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

}
```